# Android: Start activity when EditText is clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

How do I start a new activity when the user touches an EditText like in the Facebook search and Google search widget?

Setting `setOnClickListener` works only after the first click. On the first click the EditText becomes highlighted, and keyboard pops up. On second click it opens the new activity.
I do not want this, instead I want to open the activity on the very first click. How do I do it?

Comment: Is there any reason that the box that you're clicking on has to be an edit text? It would probably work as just a image that looks like an edit text, since no one is going to be typing in it anyway.

Comment: The Google search app widget does not have an `EditText`. You cannot have an `EditText` in an app widget. As @chustar suggests, having an `EditText` is ridiculous if it is not going to let the user edit text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to disable the EditText's focus in touch mode, that will make the onclick execute on the first tap:

```
<EditText ...
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
      android:editable="false"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , It saved my time, I was doing lot of R&D on it :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the input type of the EditText to InputType.TYPE_NULL:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

, which hides the soft keyboard while receiving user interaction. Start the activity:

```
public void onEditTextClick(View arg0) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Of course, the `onEditTextClick` method has to be registered to the `EditText` object:)

Answer (score 0):

Please, Try this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:onClick="search"/>
```

and

```
public void search(View view) 
{
    EditText text = (EditText)view;

    if(text.length() == 0)
        return;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This same as setting `setOnClickListener` from code. It din't work.

Comment: Hi, can i know exactly after how many characters you want to load the new activity. I removed inputType from EditText. so try it. if you know the no of character then replace 0 by that no-1.